# Demo app to test from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ad-hoc-distribution

The app that we intend to send to Apple when it is completed.

But the client in EU wants a demo app to test for download on their iphone for testing before approval for the app to be sent to Apple. The client in EU need to have a downloadable working version of the app, whether that is on their phone or their stakeholders phone all over Europe including US and UK. There are big committee in this to approve the app. I've no idea how many in a committee.

I don't think Apple accept demo or test app version. It is a straight rejection. How does that work for clients in EU to test the actual app without them installing nightmarish xcode and cordova framwork etc., etc., as most use PCs.

There must be easier solution to download a test app to people I've never met...large stakeholders in EU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's two very good tutorials on exporting the app and then adding it to a device via iTunes.

http://diaryofacodemonkey.ruprect.com/2011/03/18/ad-hoc-app-distribution-with-xcode-4/
http://www.innerfence.com/howto/install-iphone-application-ad-hoc-distribution

While the above tutorials may be able to what you need, I would suggest an easier method via TestFlightApp. I use them for all of my beta testing needs and they have been great thus far. Check them out at https://testflightapp.com

Comment: +1 for TestFlight. always have used it at work, by far the easiest to distribute over many devices

Comment: Is it long to set up the TestFlight? If I get one main stake holder to set it up on their computer and they can slot in a folder of scripts and test the app? Is that feasible.

Comment: Can I set up ad hoc or beta app from my xcode 4.5 (cordova 2.1) and sent it itunes for clients to test the app?

Comment: It's really easy to setup and they even have a desktop program that makes everything easy like uploading new app updates and notifying your users that there is a new version. http://help.testflightapp.com will give you all the help you need.

Comment: I've looked at www.innerfence.com/howto/install-iphone-application-ad-hoc-distribution as I'll need to send the .zip and .mobileprovision files to clients via email.

Comment: I mean on Xcode 4.5 and I don't need any more fiddling to set up the TestFlight to do just to create beta app. Can I use the existing xcode 4.5 that I've to create beta / test app?

Answer (score 0):

Use TestFlight - I've blogged about [Getting mobile app builds to your customers](http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2013/04/02/getting-mobile-app-builds-to-your-customers/) and that includes a brief tutorial on TestFlight with screenshots